# Determine $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that for linear transformation $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is valid: $(4,3,4)\in Im(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, linear-transformations

Determine $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that for linear transformation $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ given by matrix $        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & b & 1 \\
        1 & 2b & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ in canonical basis is valid: $(4,3,4)\in Im(f)$.

**Attempt**:

$Im(f)=span\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        a  \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        b \\
        2b \\
        \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)=\left\{c_1\begin{bmatrix}
        a  \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        b \\
        2b \\
        \end{bmatrix}+c_3\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} : c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb R\right\}$

We need to check for which $a,b\in\mathbb R$ the following system has a unique solution:

$$c_1a+c_2+c_3=4$$
$$c_1+c_2b+c_3=3$$
$$c_1+2c_2b+c_3=4$$

Using *Kronecker-Capelli's theorem*, the system will have a unique solution if $rank(A)=rank(A^{*})=3$ where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ and $A^{*}$ are $4\times 3$ matrices of the system.

Reduced echelon form of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2b & 1 \\
        0 & b & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1-a \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and for $A^{*}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2b & 1 & 4 \\
        0 & b & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1-a & \frac{4b-2ab-1}{b} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$rank(A)=rank(A^{*})=3$ if $a=2,b\neq 0$.

**Question**: Is this the only possible combination for $a$?

Comment: You don't need the solution to be unique. Thus you only need to have $rank(A)=rank(A^*)$, they need not be $3$.

Comment: @ Arnaud D. Why the solution doesn't have to be unique?

Comment: Well, $(4,3,4)\in Im(f)$ implies the existence of a solution; but you could have more than one, and nothing in your question says that it can't be the case.

Comment: Then, $\forall a$ and $\forall b,b\neq 0$ the condition is valid.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of $A$ equals $b(1-a)$. Hence, if $b\neq 0$ and $a\neq 1$, the system always has a unique solution. It is clear that it has no solution if $b=0$. Thus, you only have to check the case where $a = 1$.